# how to access sites on deep net

Tags: directory

Every link I enter returns the error:
"Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at [link].

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web."
```

I can get to "http://dirnxxdraygbifgc.onion/", but any link from there returns the above error.

Comment: If you can get to the link you mention in your last sentence, then Tor is working correctly. The other sites will all be down - .onion sites are often short-lived.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks deep-web and ordinary web sites have the same lifetime span, it's *only* a transport layer, remember. And I agree it's a strong duplicate